# Must a barbarian in a whirling frenzy take a full attack to make the extra attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, class-feature, attack

The rage variant [whirling frenzy](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/classFeatureVariants.htm#rageVariantWhirlingFrenzy) says that

> While in a whirling frenzy, the barbarian may make one extra attack in a round at his highest base attack bonus, but this attack takes a -2 penalty, as does each other attack made that round. (*Unearthed Arcana* 66)

This [thread](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?128823-3-5-Is-Whirling-Frenzy-a-bad-Rage-variant) is inconclusive. Must the creature take the full attack action to make the extra attack granted by the rage variant whirling frenzy?

Answer (score 7):

### Yes; Whirling Frenzy does not list an exception to the general multiple-attack rule

I suppose, on some level, you *have* your extra attack even if you don’t full attack, but you cannot use it unless you full attack because of this rule:

<sub>[Combat > Actions in Combat > Full-round Actions > Full Attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fullAttack)</sub>

> If you get more than one attack per round [...] for some special reason **you must use a full-round action** to get your additional attacks.

The only thing I am aware of that gets around this requirement in a general situation is *Tome of Battle*’s Snap Kick:

> When you make a melee attack with one or more
> melee weapons **(including a standard attack, full attack, or
> even a strike maneuver)**, you can make an additional attack at
> your highest attack bonus.

This parenthetical is necessary to get Snap Kick to have this behavior.

Comment: Does any effect granting an extra attack besides whirling frenzy imply using the first rule *without* specifically calling it out? Except here and the feat Snap Kick, all *other* instances of effects granting extra attacks seem to mention a full attack. (I'm just looking for another example—the perils of small sample size and all.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don’t think they have to; I don’t know of any off the top of my head.