# Is there a way to use Flurry of Blows while armored?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monk, armor

Just like the title says. Monks can't use Flurry of Blows unless unarmored. Is there a way around this? Feat, some other class that can use Flurry of Blows but isn't subject to the same restriction?

Comment: You may be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79682/8610) Buzz buzz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### “Flurry of Blows”

The Shou disciple prestige class from *Unapproachable East* allows flurry of blows to be used in light armor. Medium or heavy armor, or using a shield, still interferes with it. The Shou disciple also gains the ability to flurry with any light melee weapon, rather than only with monk weapons, though this isn’t particularly impressive.

#### “Flurry”

The exotic weapon master prestige class from *Complete Warrior* offers a “flurry of strikes” option. This only adds a single attack, and always applies a −2 penalty (i.e. it is equivalent to a 1st-level monk’s flurry of blows), but it has no armor restrictions. It must be used with an exotic double weapon or with a spiked chain.

The *Defenders of the Faith* version of the sacred fist prestige class gets a “flurry attack” feature that allows an extra attack for a −2 penalty, with no other requirements, but *Defenders of the Faith* is a 3.0e book and the 3.5e version of the sacred fist, in *Complete Divine*, does not offer this ability.

The tribal protector prestige class from *Sword and Fist* gets a “wild fighting” feature that trades a −2 attack penalty for an extra attack, with no other requirements. Mentioned because it is explicitly “[s]imilar to a monk attacking with a flurry of blows,” which of course is an accurate description.

#### Other ways to get more attacks

There are **many** ways to get more attacks. The *haste* spell, and the related *speed* special weapon property, are the most famous examples. The [swiftblade prestige class](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/prc/20070327) deserves special mention just for doing so much more with *haste*.

Not quite the same thing, but it’d be remiss to leave Two-Weapon Fighting *et al.* out here, since those also can give more attacks for a −2 penalty on all attacks. Having to use two separate weapons, having to use one-handed and light weapons, having to take numerous feats, are all significant drawbacks, however.

The [whirling frenzy rage variant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/classFeatureVariants.htm#rageVariantWhirlingFrenzy) is another, easy source of an extra attack, available to anyone who dips barbarian—which is already a good idea thanks to *Complete Champion*’s lion spirit totem option, which gives pounce.

Finally, worth mentioning is the Snap Kick feat from *Tome of Battle*: with this, you take a −2 penalty on attacks to make an extra unarmed strike, but what’s special about is—unlike almost all other options—you can use it any time you would make one or more attacks. All the other options in this answer require a full-attack, which is very limiting since you cannot move, and also cannot use some combat features that require a standard action (such as the strike maneuvers from the same *Tome of Battle*).

Attempting to list every single way to get extra attacks seems beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @Wyrmwood See [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60518/8610)

Comment: Bizarrely, Shou Disciple doesn't explicitly give the ability to flurry in light armor. I say bizarrely, because it specifies that donning medium+ armor means you can't flurry, but the class doesn't actually give you the ability to flurry (just enhances an existing one), so it must be referring to monk flurries, and thus by inference must allow monk/shou disciples to flurry in light armor. This whole class suffers from some weird editing issues/fluff-crunch dissonance.

Comment: @PoeticallyPsychotic Not disagreeing, but it *kinda* does, when it says “Light armor does not interfere with any of a Shou disciple's class abilities,” and then has a class ability allowing you to use flurry of blows (with light weapons). But yeah, not the best editing. Particularly since most players skim over the weapons and armor descriptions in the first place, and don’t expect there to be anything but basic proficiencies in there (even though many classes do have more info there).